# jQuery UI Autocomplete: minLength needed when having multiple search terms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In this demo: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple

Whenever you manually type in a term and press ", ", the autocomplete automatically displays a list of all terms, which can be troublesome if you have a list of 100,000 terms.

So how do you stop autocomplete from activating after ", "?

And how do you set a minimum length for **each term** in the input before autocomplete activates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle events when typing and after searching:

```
  $('.selector').on( "autocompletesearch", function( event, ui ) {
      var text=$('.selector').val();
      if(text[text.length-1]==',') //This validation will do the trick you want (ie: prevent to load everything after you type a ",")
          event.preventDefault();
  } );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77FvL/)

Comment: The "minLength" property is the minimum length for the whole input string, not for each term. If I set "minLength: 2", for example, "canada, a" would still activate this autocomplete to search for a term in the list containing "a" b/c "canada, a" is 9 chars, even though the term "a" is 1 char.